# mis-placement in my bibliography?

Tags: bibtex

I have used a bibliography in my report but I don't  know why it's not well structured .

this is what I had.

[image]
and this is my code in `biblio.bib`:

```
  @Article{7,
  author = {},
  title = {http://www.eewee.fr/framework-symfony/},
  journal = {},
  year = {},
  }
  @Article{8,
  author = {},
  title = {http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430014/N-Tier-Architecture-and-Tips},
  journal = {},
  year = {},
  }
   @Article{9,
   author = {},
  title = {http://www.uml-sysml.org/diagrammes-uml-et-sysml/diagramme-uml/diagramme-de-classe},
  journal = {},
  year = {},
  }
  @Article{10,
  author = {},
  title = {http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fr/SS5JSH\_9.1.2/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepd.html},
 journal = {},
 year = {},
 }
 @Article{11,
 author = {},
 title = {https://openclassrooms.com/courses/debutez-l-analyse-logicielle-avec-uml/les-differents-types-de-diagrammes},
 journal = {},
 year = {},
 }
 @Article{12,
 author = {},
 title = {files.gl3.webnode.fr/200000106-6ff9570f33/ACOO1-Chap4-DI.pdf},
 journal = {},
 year = {},
}
```

how to fix it please ?

**Edit**

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{StyleThese}
 \usepackage{url}
 \include{formatAndDefs}
 \usepackage{tabu}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{ltablex} 
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fourier}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \usepackage{graphicx}


 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,booktabs}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Netographie}
\include{chap5PFE}
\include{Annexe1}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: really you are using numbers as the citation keys? that is very strange!!   Looking at your output I an guessing that you are not using `\url` to typeset urls but you are using babel french (or similar language option)  which adds space before `:` and that ends up being the only space on the line and gets stretched.

Comment: The space is essentially generated by code you have not shown I would guess `\usepackage[french]{babel}` and your bibliography style, which is not protecting the URL field from the punctuation spacing. If you showed a small example document someone could suggest a fix.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I have edited the post . 
I found an example using numbers as the citation keys , I'm totally new to Latex .. I must change it ?

Comment: Numbers would work but they are a very strange thing to use, the whole point about bibtex is that it selects and sorts certain entries from the bib file depending on criterion specified in the document and bibtex style so you may end up with `\cite{5}` producing `[7]` which won't confuse latex or bibtex but is likely to confuse any human looking at the source. cite keys like `\label` are supposed to be symbolic names just used for internal cross referencing not related to the print form used in the document.

Comment: if you want url for titles probably simplest fix is to use `title = {\url{http://www.ibm.com/sup....}}`  adding `\url{  }` in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want url for titles probably simplest fix is to use

```
 title = {\url{http://www.ibm.com/sup....}}
```

adding `\url{ }` in each case.

a more normal bibliography would have plain text titles and a separate url field and  then (some) bibliography styles would automatically add `\url` while typesetting the url entry.